# Usage of "is planned" in sentence

Tags: grammar

I would like to don the hat as the hotel manager in your new restaurant which is planned to open next month.

In this sentence, is it correct to use "is planned"

Comment: "Is planned" is fine. "Don the hat", while comprehensible, screams out that this is not a native English speaker. (It's possible that it is idiomatic in Indian English, in which case I should amend my judgment to "speaker of British English").

Comment: @ColinFine I find nothing unidiomatic about *don the hat*. (Although I would change the preposition to *of*.) It sounds natural to me, as a native English speaker. (It's no different than *wear*, *try on*, or *try my hand at*.)

Comment: @JasonBassford: To me "don the hat"  is rather literary anyway, but to use it figuratively is very odd. "Wear the hat of", yes, maybe even "put on the hat of", but "don the hat of" sounds mannered to me.

Comment: I doubt that is "Indian English". There's a difference between Indian English and Indian English speakers using English incorrectly. "don the/a hat" is fine, but it is "don the hat as manager" is slightly odd.

Answer (score 1):

It is planned that the restaurant will open next month. Thus, it is a restaurant which is planned to open. I don't know what formal analysis would make of it, but it's a perfectly normal way to say it that most people wouldn't blink at.

Comment: "a restaurant which is planned to open" is not grammatical. "A restaurant we are planning to open" would be. or: "A restaurant [which is] planned for outdoor dining".